# cannot validate - parent keys not found

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I have the following tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE "ALMAT"."ORDER" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "CREATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "order_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
CONSTRAINT "FK_ORDER" FOREIGN KEY ("STATUS_ID")
      REFERENCES "ALMAT"."ORDER_STATUS" ("ID") ENABLE
   )

CREATE TABLE "ALMAT"."ORDER_ITEM" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ORDER_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "ORDER_ITEM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))


CREATE TABLE "ALMAT"."PRODUCT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "PRICE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(180 BYTE), 
    "CREATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "CATEGORY_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DISCOUNT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
CONSTRAINT "FK_STATUS" FOREIGN KEY ("STATUS_ID")
      REFERENCES "ALMAT"."PRODUCT_STATUS" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_DISCOUNT" FOREIGN KEY ("DISCOUNT_ID")
      REFERENCES "ALMAT"."DISCOUNT" ("ID") ENABLE
   )
```

when I try to add constraints to ORDER_ITEM throws an error: "an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has child records."

```
alter table order_item
    add constraint fk_orderitem_productid
        foreign key (product_id)
        references product(id);
    
alter table order_item
    add constraint fk_orderitem_orderid
        foreign key (order_id)
        references "ORDER"(id);
```

Other than that, I tried to delete records that do not match the parent table, but this did not work:

```
delete from order_item where exists(
    SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM order_item WHERE order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM "ORDER")
)
```

Comment: Which constraint is throwing the error?

Comment: both constraints

Comment: Your `delete` query *does work*, but is *wrong written*, it will remove all rows from `order_item` table. See the correct version below.

Answer (score 2):

Les't assume following scenario

```
alter table order_item
    add constraint fk_orderitem_orderid
        foreign key (order_id)
        references "ORDER"(id);  


ORA-02298: cannot validate (ALMAT.FK_ORDERITEM_ORDERID) - parent keys not found
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
```

**This means:**
You have in `ORDER_ITEM` an ORDER_ID that doesn't exists in "ORDER". You may spot those IDs with following query

```
SELECT ORDER_ID from "ORDER_ITEM" 
MINUS
SELECT ID from "ORDER"
```

To get rid of those rows do following

```
DELETE from  order_item
WHERE ORDER_ID in 
(SELECT ORDER_ID from "ORDER_ITEM" 
MINUS
SELECT ID from "ORDER"
);

1 row deleted.
```

Now you can safely add the constrait

```
alter table order_item
    add constraint fk_orderitem_orderid
        foreign key (order_id)
        references "ORDER"(id);
        
Table ORDER_ITEM altered.
```